# Multidimensional object/array into a hierarchy list using ng-repeat filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
{
   "status":"1",
   "department":{
      "ERP":{
         "ERP child 1":[],
         "ERP child 2":[]
      },
      "Development":{
         "PHP":{
            "INT":{
               "TINYINT":[]
            }
         }
      },
      "string":[]
   }
}
```

I'm unable to create a hierarchy (tree structure) from above multidimensional object using ng-repeat filter in angularjs, Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please describe more detailed, what you want to do...

Comment: I want to create a tree structure, where ERP and Development are parent item. ERP will have 2 children ERP child 1 and ERP child 2. Development would have PHP as a child. PHP further will have INT and TINYINT as its child. let me know if it still doesn't help you to understand what i want.

Comment: Is the JSON structure always like your example. Because it's not so easy to deal with an object with unknown 'keys'. The number of members in the array does'nt matter but it's hard to process dynamically objects with unknown members.

Comment: Do you suggest to have keys? I can try to modify the structure to have the keys? I can have any number of children inside any item.

Answer (score 0):

I make an example and you can give me some feedback, if this matches your idea.

First in your controller parse the JSON object and add it to the `$scope`

```
$scope.myObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then inside your html code you can do something like that

```
    <div ng-repeat="child in myObject.department.ERP.ERP_child_1">
           <p>{{child}}</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="child in myObject.department.ERP.ERP_child_2">
           <p>{{child}}</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="child in myObject.department.Development.PHP.INT.TINYINT">
           <p>{{child}}</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="child in myObject.department.string">
           <p>{{child}}</p>
    </div>
```

But this only works if you know the object members.

Comment: Thanks for the example, But looking at the example, I guess i can only access the last child. I want to get whole hierarchy in a tree format.